# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? on mac

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine, docker-container

If I run any docker command it's saying

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I am using mac latest version.

docker version:

```
Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4
```

docker-compose version:

```
docker-compose version 1.23.1, build b02f1306
```

docker-machine version:

```
docker-machine version 0.16.0, build 702c267f
```

I tried some solutions but did work.

Answer (score 2):

```
open --background -a Docker
```

worked for me perfectly.